# How to set image for ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I am trying to make an `ImageView` swiping the images on touch motion, but when I motion to the next image, I got an error saying:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
>   on a null object reference
>               at com.semicolon.www.slider.MainActivity.onTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:48)

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageSwitcher Switch;
    ImageView image;
    float intialX;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private int columnIndex, position = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Switch = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                intialX = event.getX();
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float finalX = event.getX();
                if (intialX > finalX) {
                    Drawable r = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2);
                    image.setBackground(r);
                }
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

So how I can fix this error and put an image (or background) for `ImageView`?

Comment: Are you sure the id is correct?
Try adding logs after setting `image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);`, like `if(image == null) Log.d("MainActivity", "image is null!");`

Comment: @FlorianSchrofner you are right, the id for ImageView was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try using viewPager instead of a ImageSwitcher

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setImageResource` method instead of `setBackground`:

```
image.setImageResource (R.drawable.img2);
```